# How to force Facebook Connect to use iFrame instead of overlay for authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have FB Connect on my site which allows users to authorize the site to access their FB profile data.  I'm using the FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog function to initiate the connect process and grant permissions, how can I force it to always use the popup window connect dialog instead of the overlay method?  My page has an incredible amount of complex javascript which is somehow causing the overlay iFrame to load the page itself in the frame instead of the facebook connect page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out..

FB.Facebook.init(APIKEY, "xd_receiver.htm", {"forceBrowserPopupForLogin":true});